How to retry for a period of time with sidekiq?
I am looking for a way to limit a job, to be retried only for 2 days or 48 hours. After which it should be cancelled, unless processed. I know with sidekiq_options, I can limit the number of retries. Though, what I'm looking for is cancelling a job if it doesn't get processed within 2 days.

As of Sidekiq 7.1.3, one can retry for a period of time:
class NonRetryableJob
  include Sidekiq::Job
  sidekiq_options retry_for: 48.hours

  def perform(...)
  end
end

Reference - https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling

Sidekiq offer these options for retries:
sidekiq_options retry: 5 # Only five retries and then to the Dead Job Queue
sidekiq_options retry: false # job will be discarded if it fails
sidekiq_options retry_for: 24.hours # retry after 24 hours
sidekiq_options retry: 5, dead: false # will retry 5 times and then disappear
